# Laravel Mail::send() method sends empty email, and logs template when queued

Tags: laravel, email, view, queue

I encountered a problem with email sending under Laravel queue.
I have a Controller, like

```
public function myFunction()
{
    .
    .

    SendWarrantyCardByEmail::dispatch(
        $request['card_number'],
        $request['email'],
        $request['is_foreign'],
        $this->warrantyCardFactory
    );
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have the Job, which handle method is the following:

```
public function handle(WarrantyCardFactory $warrantyCardFactory): void
{
    $firstItem = WarrantyCard::cardNumber($this->cardNumber)
                            ->first();

    $pdfString = $warrantyCardFactory->getPdfasString($this->cardNumber);

    App::setLocale(SelectableCurrency::getLocaleByCurrency($firstItem->currency));
    Mail::send(
        'emails.warranty_card.warranty_send',
        ['firstItem' => $firstItem],
        function (Message $message) use ($pdfString, $firstItem) {
            $message->to($this->email, $this->email);
            $message->from(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name'));
            $message->subject(trans('warranty_card.warranty_card_arrived'));
            $message->attachData($pdfString, $firstItem->file_name);
        }
    );
}
```

And ofcourse, $warrantyCardFactory resolved well from AppServiceProvider.

I can set the environment variable to

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

This case everything working well. The attachment can be download, the embed image visible, and the template shows well.
But when i change it to

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

The template is missing in the email, and showing as log in the stdout_logfile of the supervisor.
The supervisor config is the following:

```
  [program:myprogram]
  process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
  command=php8.2 <myPath>artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=1800
  autostart=true
  autorestart=true
  stopasgroup=true
  killasgroup=true
  user=vagrant
  numprocs=1
  redirect_stderr=true
  stdout_logfile=<myPath>/storage/logs/queueworker.log
  stopwaitsecs=3600
```

When i trying to run it from command line

```
artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=1800 autostart=true
```

The outcome is exactly the same: the email arrives with attachment, and seems like no error, but the template is missing, and is printed in the log.

I tried

- outsource email to Mailable
- outsoure email as qued Mailable
- drop Job, and use directly a Mailable as queued

But the outcome was the same.
I suspect, there is a problem, when the view is rendered, but did not found it, because it's hard to debug.

Maybe a setting, or .env variable is missing at me.
Does anybody have idea what can be the problem?